# if the booking id is varriable character, how to return last inserted id in codegniter

Tags: codeigniter, mysql-insert-id

> Blockquote

how  to  return  last  inserted   id ,  if  the   booking  id  is  variable character  in   codeigniter**

> **strong text**

**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using codeigniter 3 use this:

```php
$this->db->insert_id();
```

If you are using codeigniter 4 use this:

```php
$this->db->insertID();
```

all this should be within you model or where you called the database connect.
I hope this help you else call my attentions okay?

Comment: actually  iam    using   $this->db->insert_id();  this  methode,  but  my  bookind  id  was  varraiable  character   so the  last   inserted  id  always  shows  0

Comment: Do you mean you store the $this->db->insert_id() into a variable like `$id = $this->db->insert_id();` . if this is what you do please return the value of the id to get the value you are looking for. Example `function insertbooking () { // your query command here return id = $this->db->insert_id();}` the call it anywhere like this ` echo insert booking()`. I hope this will help you else call my attention